# Read txt file's lines in JS (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing

I want to read a text file (.txt) using Node.js. I need to push each of text's lines into array, like this:

```
a
b
c
```

to

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var fs  = require("fs");
var array = fs.readFileSync(path).toString().split('\n');
```

Or the asynchronous variant :

```
var fs  = require("fs");
fs.readFile(path, function(err, f){
    var array = f.toString().split('\n');
    // use the array
});
```

Comment: Why the `toString()` on the return value of `fs.readFile`?

Comment: readFileSync returns a buffer, which has no method split. Without the toString, you get an exception.

Comment: I was talking about `// use the array
}).toString(); <- this one`

Comment: @Dogbert I just saw and fixed this one. Bad copy-paste from the sync version...